# writeStream proccesing data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to writeStream processing data(structured streaming data) to mongodb. I can send data from kafka to spark and I can process the data. But I can't send the data to mongodb from spark. and I am getting this error

```
<console>:55: error: value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
        val df3 = rdd.map({ case (word: String, count: Int)
```

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.log4j.{Logger, Level}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
    import com.mongodb.spark._
    import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming._
    import com.mongodb.spark.config._
    import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
    
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("localhost").appName("ReadFromKafka").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
        
    val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "IP:9092").option("subscribe", "test").load()

    val df2 = df.select($"key".cast(StringType), $"value".cast(StringType))
    
    val df3 = df2.select($"value").as[String].flatMap(_.split("\\W+")).groupBy("value").count().sort(f.desc("count"))   
        
    case class WordCount(word: String, count: Int)

    df3.foreach({ rdd =>
    import spark.implicits._
    val df3 = rdd.map({ case (word: String, count: Int)
            => WordCount(word, count) }).toDF()
    df3.write.mode("append").mongo()
    })
```

Comment: why don't you directly write `df3` as `MongoSpark.save(df3)` here is an example https://koiralo.com/2020/06/21/how-to-read-and-write-data-from-mongodb-with-spark3/

Comment: MongoSpark.save(df3)

    MongoSpark.save(df3.write.option("collection","spark").mode("overwrite").format("mongo"))

Comment: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();; error I am getting

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but I will write you back Once I try it.